# Transaction Unconfirmed after 12 hours! Help!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I've seen this happening but haven't found any clear answers on what to do, i sent about $30 worth of coins to an address (im sure its correct) and its unconfirmed after about 12 hours. you can see the transaction [here](https://blockchain.info/tx/b8f39f0173748a35c23b84571fc81eb95bcce652462c1777d38776b77eac8464). Any Help????